# Проверка двух определенных символов, стоящих перед кареткой

Tags: delphi

Так выглядит проверка на один определенный символ, стоящий перед кареткой, а как реализовать проверку на два определенных символа?

```
if Char(Memo1.Text[Memo1.SelStart])<>'н' then ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Memo1.Text[Memo1.SelStart+1]`?

**UPD** Вы не поняли. Надо так:

```
if (Memo1.Text[Memo1.SelStart]<>'о') or (Memo1.Text[Memo1.SelStart+1]<>'н') then ...
```

или если понятнее будет:

```
if not((Memo1.Text[Memo1.SelStart]='о') and (Memo1.Text[Memo1.SelStart+1]='н')) then ...
```

Comment: К сожалению, нет. (Memo1.Text[Memo1.SelStart])<>'он', если один символ, то срабатывает, а если два, то никакого эффекта.

Comment: @hkpp, обновил ответ.

Comment: проверку на выход за границы не забудьте добавить.

Comment: То, что нужно! Большое спасибо! Для моей ситуации верным оказалось: if not((Memo1.Text[Memo1.SelStart-1]='о') and (Memo1.Text[Memo1.SelStart]='н')) then ...

Comment: @hkpp, эти выражения эквивалентны.